# AWS Redirecting route53 to S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I am having trouble redirecting route53 domain to my S3 bucket.
I have created a working bucket which you can access trough this url:

http://linas.me.uk.s3-website.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/

The bucket name matches domain name and I am able to setup new record set with linas.me.uk alias target. However when you try visiting http://linas.me.uk 404 gets thrown.

I have tried anything I could think of or find googling but I have hit the wall it seems, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: That subdomain doesn't resolve any IP, try with `dig linas.me.uk @1.1.1.1`. Maybe you should set a subdomain, like www.linas.me.uk

Comment: What does your route53 entry look like?